# pass value to a php session when clicking on <li value=xx>

Tags: php, jquery, session

ex.

```
<li value="123">123</li>
 <li value="456">456</li>
```

howto  pass value `<li value="xxx">` to a php session when clicking on `<li value ="xxx">`

Comment: here `ajax` comes in action

Comment: `<li>` has no `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a file that looks like this

```
// update_session.php

<?php session_start(); 
if (isset($_POST["val"])){
       $_SESSION["val"] = $_POST["val"];
}
```

Then for your html you would have (note I changed attribute to a data-value because value is not a valid attribute for li whereas the data- prefix attributes are valid.)

```
<ul id ='my_ul'>
<li data-value="123">123</li>
<li data-value="456">456</li>
</ul>
```

And you jquery (in a document ready block) would look like this.

```
$('#my_ul').on("click", "li", function(){
   $.ajax("update_session.php",{method:"post", data:{val:$(this).attr("data-value")}}); 
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this).attr("data-value")`? Also, you have an unnecessary `;` in there.

Answer (score 1):

`<li>` doesn't have a `value` attribute. However, you could put a button inside the list item and send that. For instance:

```
<li><button name="button1" value="123">123</button></li>
<li><button name="button2" value="456">456</button></li>
```

Then just style `button` to not look like a button.

If you include these elements in a form, their values would be accessible in your PHP script through either the `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays depending on how you send it.